# What is precapture sequence in android's Camera 2 API

Tags: android, android-camera2

I think it may be confusing, because in many examples, like open-camera repository, google camera2basic (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/73e125d3c9131361ec90302f56f8bc91e31c3d13/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java#L793) there are example code for running precapture. But in official documentation you can also find a separate field in CameraResult, called AE_PRECAPTURE(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata#CONTROL_AE_STATE_PRECAPTURE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precapture has 2 meanings.
First it is a sequence of requests, where we get focus, wait for AE/AWB to converge.
Second one is a part of AE converge process, where camera is searching for best exposure.

So the precapture sequence consists of 3 requests:

1. Where you set AF mode to AUTO, and wait for focus.
2. Where you set AE/AWB mode to AUTO, and wait for converge. Now you "Good values" according to documentation https://source.android.com/devices/camera/camera3_3Amodes#ae-wb , but you should run PRECAPTURE as the part of AE
3. Where you set PRECAPTURE_START, and wait again for AE converged, then you may lock it, and take still picture

Comment: To add to @404pio's answer; it doesn't need to be 3 separate requests, you can also pack the AF, AE, and AWB triggers in the same request, then wait for the values to Focus/Converge in the repeating request listener.